# Circular linked list head doesn't update when inserting at position 0?

Tags: java, circular-list

I have a circular linked list created. I originally insert all the information to the end.

My insertAtEnd method.

```java
public void insertAtEnd(Card data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
 
    if (head == null) {
        newNode.next = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node current = head;
        do {
            current = current.next;
        } while (current.next != head);
        newNode.next = head;
        current.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Everything outputs fine then, but when I try to use insertAtPos method while inserting into position 0, an infinite loop happens for some reason. While debugging, I noticed that the head reference of the last node still shows to the old head. Why does this happen?

My insertAtPos method

```java
public void insertAtPos(Card data, int position) {
    if (position < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid position. Position cannot be negative");
        return;
    }
 
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (position == 0) {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node current = head;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        while (current != null && currentIndex < position - 1) {
            current = current.next;
            currentIndex++;
        }
        if (current == null) {
            System.out.println("Position is out of bounds");
            return;
        }
        newNode.next = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Head is a global variable in that class, so I guess it shouldn't be problem that some methods can or can't edit it?

Comment: You've done all the debugging work for us... When inserting at 0, one thing to do is update `last.next` to point at the new head. Which of the two commands you currently have does this? (spoiler: neither) You may have to find the last node first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if (position == 0)` path:

- Sets the 'next' of the newly created node to point at what used to be the first node in the list.
- Sets the 'global' pointer to the first node in the list to this newly created object.

That's literally the two lines you have in there. You ask:

> I noticed that the head reference of the last node still shows to the old head. Why does it happen?

The answer is the rather obvious: Because.. you didn't change it.

Possibly you're confused about how java works. It's not like math. When you write something like:

```
someNode.next = head;
```

That is **not** a mathematical aliasing concept. That statement doesn't mean: "`head` and `someNode.next` are to be deemed as aliases; they are the same, now and forever". No, it just means: "Take the **current** value of the `head` variable, and update the value of the `next` field in whatever object the **current** value of `someNode` is pointing to to be the same value; they are not equivalent and updating either one later does not magically modify the other one".

So, you'd have to go find the last node in the chain (with a loop of some sort) and tell it that its `.next` should be the newly created node.